# wnmp nginx configuration for Zend Framework 1.12 (Windows, nginx, mariadb, php 7)

Tags: windows, zend-framework, nginx

I have zend framework 1.12 based site with .htaccess content as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

I installed wnmp on windows 7 professional to test Windows, nginx, mariadb, php7

The home page on local host works great. PHP 7 and mariaDB worked great and showed data nd images on the home page localhost ( http://localhost )

I tried many things also stackoverflow's example [Apache rewrite rule to NGINX for HHVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481058/apache-rewrite-rule-to-nginx-for-hhvm)

My urls for the host straight forward
like
http://localhost/conference/sessions/date/2015-04/12/page/1
conference - controller
sessions - action
request params date, and page with respective values

here  is what I have in my nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    # Max value 16384
    worker_connections  8192;
    # Accept multiple connections
    multi_accept on;
}

# Settings that affect all server blocks
http {
    include php_processes.conf;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  logs/access.log;

    sendfile on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 SSLv3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5:!DSS; 
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    gzip  on;
    # http server

# Begin HTTP Server
server {
    listen 80; # IPv4
    server_name localhost;

    ## Parametrization using hostname of access and log filenames.
    access_log logs/localhost_access.log;
    error_log logs/localhost_error.log;

    ## Root and index files.
    root html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    ## If no favicon exists return a 204 (no content error).
    location = /favicon.ico {
        try_files $uri =204;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    ## Don't log robots.txt requests.
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    ## Try the requested URI as files before handling it to PHP.
    location / {

        ## Regular PHP processing.
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files  $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   php_processes;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        ## Static files
        location ~* \.(?:css|gif|htc|ico|js|jpe?g|png|swf)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
            ## fell swoop.
            tcp_nodelay off;
            ## Set the OS file cache.
            open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=120s;
            open_file_cache_valid 45s;
            open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
            open_file_cache_errors off;
        }

        ## Keep a tab on the 'big' static files.
        location ~* ^.+\.(?:ogg|pdf|pptx?)$ {
            expires 30d;
            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
            ## fell swoop.
            tcp_nodelay off;
        }
        } # / location

} 
# End HTTP Server

# Begin HTTPS Server
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  key.pem;
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    ## Parametrization using hostname of access and log filenames.
    access_log logs/localhost_access.log;
    error_log logs/localhost_error.log;

    ## Root and index files.
    root html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    ## If no favicon exists return a 204 (no content error).
    location = /favicon.ico {
        try_files $uri =204;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    ## Don't log robots.txt requests.
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    ## Try the requested URI as files before handling it to PHP.
    location / {

        ## Regular PHP processing.
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files  $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   php_processes;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        ## Static files are served directly.
        location ~* \.(?:css|gif|htc|ico|js|jpe?g|png|swf)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
            ## fell swoop.
            tcp_nodelay off;
            ## Set the OS file cache.
            open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=120s;
            open_file_cache_valid 45s;
            open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
            open_file_cache_errors off;
        }

        ## Keep a tab on the 'big' static files.
        location ~* ^.+\.(?:ogg|pdf|pptx?)$ {
            expires 30d;
            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
            ## fell swoop.
            tcp_nodelay off;
        }
        } # / location
} # End HTTPS Server
}
```

Please help me with this one; I am new to nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add in server configuration `server {...}` redirection to `index.php` for resources that are not found

```
try_files $uri @missing;
location @missing {
    rewrite .* /index.php;
}
```

`root ...;` should point to public directory that contain `index.php`

Comment: on line 41 I have used `root = html`, html is the public directory with wnmp installation. which is at location c:\wnmp\html @MaxP

Comment: Thanks @MaxP. index.php is at the root. Finally got it working. I added `try_files $uri $uri/ @missing;` just before end of `} # / location` and thenaoutside of that I added `location @missing {
  rewrite (.*) /index.php;
 }`. After that ran into many errors as code needed to be fixed for PHP7. the I got status code 502  bad gateway. I added `fastcgi_buffers 16 16k; 
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;` to fix them. I would like to understand what they mean and how do we decide the buffers abd buffer sizes. This would be critical for go live when we have a lot many users visiting the site.